# paho: Control GPIO over MQTT

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, gpio, paho

I have a script running on a external RaspberryPi, so I can control the onboard GPIO over MQTT.
The script will be started via system as a service. (`status = active`)

```
# python 3.6
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import json

from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client
from socket import timeout

# MQTT broker settings
broker = '192.*.*.*'
port = 1883
topic = "RaspberryMK/GPIO"
client_id = '2223'
username = '****'
password = '****'

# Relays GPIO numbers
RELAIS_1_GPIO = 22 # K1 - Relay 1
RELAIS_2_GPIO = 27 # K2 - Spare

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # GPIO Numbers instead of board numbers
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.OUT) # GPIO Assign mode
GPIO.setup(RELAIS_2_GPIO, GPIO.OUT) # GPIO Assign mode

GPIO.output(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.HIGH) # Switch off RELAIS_1_GPIO
GPIO.output(RELAIS_2_GPIO, GPIO.HIGH) # Switch off RELAIS_2_GPIO

def relay_on(Relay):
    GPIO.output(Relay, GPIO.LOW) # out
    print("GPIO LOW")
    
def relay_off(Relay):
    GPIO.output(Relay, GPIO.HIGH) # out
    print("GPIO HIGH")
    
def getInfo():
    if GPIO.input(RELAIS_1_GPIO) == 1:
        relaisstatus = "Uit"
    else:
        relaisstatus = "Aan"

def connect_mqtt():
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)
            
    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client
    
def publish(client):
    msg_count = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        msg = f"messages: {msg_count}"
        result = client.publish(topic, msg)
        # result: [0, 1]
        status = result[0]
        if status == 0:
            print(f"Send `{msg}` to topic `{topic}`")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to send message to topic {topic}")
        msg_count += 1

def subscribe(client: mqtt_client):
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print(f"Received `{msg.payload.decode()}` from `{msg.topic}` topic")
        
        if msg.topic == "RaspberryMK/GPIO/GPIO22":
            if msg.payload.decode() == "ON":
                relay_on(RELAIS_1_GPIO)
            elif msg.payload.decode() == "OFF":
                relay_off(RELAIS_1_GPIO)
            else:
                print ("Failed")
        elif msg.topic == "RaspberryMK/GPIO/GPIO27":
            if msg.payload.decode() == "ON":
                relay_on(RELAIS_2_GPIO)
            elif msg.payload.decode() == "OFF":
                relay_off(RELAIS_2_GPIO)
            else:
                print ("Failed")
        else:
            print ("Failed")
   
    client.subscribe(topic+"/GPIO22")
    client.subscribe(topic+"/GPIO27")
    client.on_message = on_message
    
def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    
    subscribe(client)
    client.loop_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

The script can run for a few days and suddenly I cannot control the GPIO any more.
The output is will be:

```
Connected to MQTT Broker!
Connected to MQTT Broker!
Connected to MQTT Broker!
```

So it looks like it is continuous trying to connect to the MQQT broker.

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: I would recommend to switch to use `libgpiod` and its facilities instead of some custom approach.

Comment: So does `Connected to MQTT..` come up continuously? If its occasional then I'd guess that the issue is that you are not resubscriing - see [the docs](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#usage-and-api) re subscribing in on_connect.